# Internet Seems To Disconnect When I Use More Resources

Tags: internet, resources, connection

So the past couple of weeks, my internet disconnects and connects continuously. If I am running just a couple programs like for example skype it's fine, however if I run skype, firefox, and an online game it seems to disconnect my internet - and after about 4-6 minutes it comes right back on. Any help would great!

Comment: What type of connection do you have (adsl, ads2, vdsl, cable, fiber, etc)? What is the connection speed? How far are you from the CO (if you know)?

Comment: cable internet, and 7mbsp

Comment: If you are using a router before your cable modem, try bypassing the router and see if the issue persists. If so, call up your cable company, there is likely something wrong between your junction box and the CMTS.

Comment: Also, do you have upload/download limits per month?